Vary header middleware for HTMx
There's a common pattern with HTMx to return different responses based on hx-.. request headers and it's recommended to add corresponding Vary response headers:

Be mindful that if your server can render different content for the same URL depending on some other headers, you need to use the Vary response HTTP header. For example, if your server renders the full HTML when the HX-Request header is missing or false, and it renders a fragment of that HTML when HX-Request: true, you need to add Vary: HX-Request. https://htmx.org/docs/#caching

It seems like a good use case for middleware, as:

The same Vary header value should be used on all responses for a given URL, including 304 Not Modified responses and the "default" response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary

So my questions are:

Are there any drawbacks to adding the Vary: hx-request, hx-target, hx-trigger, hx-trigger-name header to every single response?
Are there reasons to add it to request methods other than GET and HEAD?


It depends on your cache strategy, but I think it's better to avoid middlewares altogether and handle caching in a case-by-case scenario.
The reason is that you may end up with all sorts of different headers combination later on (not just the htmx one), so having it available on every request may be an overkill and result in bunch of overridden logic.
As for second question - No. The recommended approach is to apply caching only on data fetch.

"The recommended approach is to apply caching only on data fetch" - the second quote from the question seems to claim the opposite. Am I misreading it? I wonder if there's any edge cases.

I think it just indcates that you need to apply Vary to any response coming from specific url, which can be different (eg fresh set of data). They don't mean any given "method" imo. You can of course apply cache for non-fetch requests. The recommended way is avoid it unless you don't have a choice, in which case you would need to providethe exact problem with code example etc. SO is probably not the best place to ask about opinions and recommendations whithout a having specific issue.
